# VBA How to pass formatted text from Excel to MS Word

Tags: vba, excel

I've requirement where in I need to compare two samples of text in Excel using VBA. Since each text sample is more than 3000 characters in LEN, I use a Userform.TextBox field fetch,storing them into string variables.

Next, I use a VBA code that I found here by '*mikerickson*': [VBA routine to comp](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/714927-visual-basic-applications-routine-perform-text-diff-2.html)

To compare the texts. 
The problem is that the output of this code is input into a Cell: A1. 
Since the text samples contain more than 3000 characters each, the result is not displayed in A1 since excel has limit on the number of characters per cell.

I would like to know how to get the result (with all the formatting like underline and strikethrough) in to an MS Word Doc.

Currently, this is the code used to output to cell A1.

```
strResult = ComparedText(strOne, strTwo, olStart, olLength, nwStart, nwLength)

With outCell.Cells(1, 1)
    .Clear
    .Value = strResult
    For i = LBound(olStart) To UBound(olStart)
        If olStart(i) <> 0 Then

            With .Characters(olStart(i), olLength(i)).Font
                .ColorIndex = 3
                .StrikeThrough = True
            End With
        End If
    Next i
    For i = LBound(nwStart) To UBound(nwStart)
        If nwStart(i) <> 0 Then
            With .Characters(nwStart(i), nwLength(i)).Font
                .ColorIndex = 4
                .Underline = True
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Need a replacement code here which will enter **strResult** into a word document with the exact same formatting for the mismatches as in the code above.

Hoping somebody helps. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get it from Cell A1 to Word. If the data in Cell A1 is being truncated then we'll have to dig deeper.

```
Set wordy = CreateObject("Word.Application")

wordy.Documents.Add
Sheets(1).Range("A1").Copy
wordy.Documents(1).ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteRTF
wordy.Visible = True

'wordy.Quit

Set wordy = Nothing
```

If we can insert strResult into Word and perform the formatting there, then this might work for you...

```
Set wordy = CreateObject("Word.Application")

wordy.Documents.Add
wordy.Documents(1).ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertAfter Text:=strResult
wordy.Documents(1).Range.Select
wordy.Visible = True

With wordy.Selection

For i = LBound(olStart) To UBound(olStart)
    If olStart(i) <> 0 Then

        For j = olStart(i) To (olStart(i) + olLength(i) - 1)
            With .Characters(j).Font
                .ColorIndex = 3
                .Strikethrough = True
            End With
        Next j
    End If
Next i

For i = LBound(nwStart) To UBound(nwStart)
    If nwStart(i) <> 0 Then
        For j = nwStart(i) To (nwStart(i) + nwLength(i) - 1)
            With .Characters(j).Font
                .ColorIndex = 4
                .Underline = True
            End With
        Next j
    End If
Next i
End With

Set wordy = Nothing
```

This may not be the most efficient code but should hopefully get you going in the right direction. I had to create the *j* loops because it looks like in Word the [Characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197930(v=office.15).aspx) object can only access one character at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Porcupine911. However, when there are 3000 characters, not all of those get copied from A1 to the word document. Hence theres a need for something that will directly copy the strResult into the Word Doc.

Comment: Well, it looks like we can get strResult into Word with `wordy.Documents(1).ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeText Text:=strResult` but then we'll have to do the formatting in Word.

Comment: I just did a test with 4000 characters and there was no issue with the answer I posted. Even this old Excel 2003 [Knowledge Base Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211580) seems to indicate that it should work fine.

Comment: Need the formatting to be done during runtime, Porcupine911. Thats the requirement. There is a function to compare and then result is formatted to highlight the mismatches. So, beats the whole purpose if I can't automate the formatting. The formatting works fine when the output is put across to Cell A1 with the above code. But it needs to happen when the strResult is being placed into a Word Doc as well. Please help.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. I can put 4000 characters with formatting into cell A1 and it goes into Word with formatting intact.

Comment: The issue is simple Porcupine911: There should be no intermediate excel Cells involved. Its need to write the strResult directly into the Word document. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, for some reason I thought you had the formatted data in cell A1 already. So sorry! I'm still looking for some kind of solution for you but nothing yet.

Comment: I think I've made some progress but I have to get to paying work now. Perhaps tonight or tomorrow morning I'll have something for ya.

Comment: It'd be one hell of a relief if you manage a solution for this. Thanks, Porcupine911.

Comment: Can we do the formatting in word after we insert strResult there? if so, I think I have something that could work. I'll add it to my answer above.

Comment: Yup! That works for me :) Fantastic work around. Kudos!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks a million!,Porcupine911

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I was able to help.